# Multiple value lookup accross excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vlookup

I have a master worksheet and a Extract worksheet.
I want to extract data from Extract sheet and present it as follows in the master sheet.

Data is as follows:

```
Extract Sheet
--------------------------------------
Fruit    Nutrients    Proportion
Apple    Calcium      10
Apple    Vitamin B    20
Mango    Vitamin A    50
Lemon    Vitamin C    30
Lemon    Vitamin A    10

Master Sheet
--------------------------------------------------------
Fruit    Calcium    Vitamin A    Vitamin B    Vitamin C
Apple    10         0             20           0
Mango    0          50            0            0
Lemon    0          10            0            30
```

I have used Excel Array functions SMALL and INDEX but 
I am unable to get the Proportion value in the master table. 
I keep getting #NUM error

Please help me with the same and guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please change the formatting so that only code is highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put your sample data and results into a single worksheets as per the following image but you should be able to move the *Extract* to another worksheet and transcribe the formula for your own purposes.

[image]

The standard formula in F2 is `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$5)+(($A$2:$A$6<>$E2)+($B$2:$B$6<>F$1))*1E+99,,))),0)`. Fill both right and down as necessary. You mentioned using `SMALL` but you have no duplicated values across the two criteria columns so I think this is closer to what you require. Post back a comment if you do need a `SMALL` function with *k* picking the first, second, etc.

Comment: The formula works, but can you explain it in detail.
I am able to apply the concept in my sheet but only able to do so for 6 rows after that not able to retrieve value... I have a sheet with 20000 rows ... can you explain in detail.. So I can make the changes necessary in the formula.

Comment: @sau6402 - the most common problem with transcribing this style of formula is setting the `ROW()` part. In the above, `ROW(1:5)` is not the actual row on the worksheet. It is the *position within* C2:C6. If your actual data had the *Proportion* in C10:C20000 then you would use `ROW($1:$19991)`. C10:C20000 and ROW(1:19991) reference the same number of rows. Other than that, just keep the number of rows in the lookup table the same (e.g. A10:A20000, B10:B20000 & C10:C20000). It is also important to keep the `$` markers in the same positions so that copying to other cells shifts correctly.

Comment: I had done those changes... but took row value as ROW($1:$20000)
Thanx a lot sir.
Can you please explain the *1E+99 in the formula.
Also could you share links where I can learn such detail level excel

Comment: @sau6402 - The 1E+99 is intended to throw an error by adding an very large number to the `ROW()`. If column A doesn't equal E2 OR column B doesn't equal F1, then 1E+99 is added to the *position within* column C and that's never going to be the `MIN` of anything. In the case where there are no matches, 1E+99 is larger than the number of rows on the worksheet so an error is thrown which is caught by `IFERROR` and a zero is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(('Extract '!$A$2:$A$6=$A2)*('Extract '!$B$2:$B$6=B$1)),'Extract '!$C$2:$C$6),0)